# Length of PCP Proofs

Tags: complexity-theory, interactive-proof-systems

Suppose a language $L$ has a non-adaptive PCP verifier which uses at most $r(n)$ random coins, and queries at most $q(n)$ locations of the proof, on inputs of length $n$. How can we show that there is a PCP verifier $V'$ for $L$ that uses proofs of length at most $2^{r(n)}q(n)$?

I understand that the verifier can query at most $2^{r(n)}q(n)$ locations of the proof. How does the verifier 'know' a map from these queried locations to $\{1, 2, \dots, 2^{r(n)}q(n)\}$? For example, I think an interesting case is when $r(n)=n, q(n) = O(1)$.

Comment: I suggest ignoring this comment. The idea is that there are only so many queries, so there's no point in the proof being any longer. In practice the indexing issues you seem to be worried about do not arise.

Comment: You can use hashing to get close to $2^{r(n)} q(n)$, at a small cost in parameters.